# Rails3 and Sass::Plugin::options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, nameerror

When I try to add `Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compact` to environment.rb

When I try to start up my server I get:

> uninitialized constant Sass (NameError)

I have added `gem 'haml', '3.0.0'` to my *Gemfile*.

Anybody ran into this?

Answer (score 6):

I tried what you described and it worked fine for me.  I'm using haml 3.0.4 which is the latest version.  You may want to run a `gem update haml` on your system and try again.  The list of changes from 3.0.0 to 3.0.4 are at http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html

I also suggest not putting this in your environment.rb, but instead create a `config/initializers/sass_config.rb` file and put your SASS config there.  Mine looks like this:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:property_syntax] = :old
Sass::Plugin.remove_template_location("./public/stylesheets/sass")
Sass::Plugin.add_template_location("./app/stylesheets")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, and using the sass_config.rb file worked for my case - it seems the calls in environment.rb are occurring before the plugin init.rb is loaded.

Comment: Using HAML 3.0.18 had the exact same problem. Moving the code to initializer solved the problem.