# How can I change the CSS output formatting style for SASS

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I have read [this document](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style) regarding setting the options but cannot seem to do it. I've been inside the environment.rb class but not sure what I am doing with the Symbol => Object as I am unfamiliar with Ruby. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this: `sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style`**`OPTION`**
where **`OPTION`** is one of these: **`compressed`, `compact`, `nested`,** or **`expanded`**.

Example for compressed:`sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style`**`compressed`**

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

Looks like there may be some initialization issues when using environment.rb to set up sass configurations. Follow the instructions here:

[Rails3 and Sass::Plugin::options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807214/rails3-and-sasspluginoptions)

Good luck.

---- Original answer
Under what circumstances are you using sass? Are you running Rails? I pulled this from the sass docs:

> Options
>
> Options can be set by setting the
>   Sass::Plugin.options hash in
>   environment.rb in Rails or config.ru
>   in Rack…
>
> Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compact

Just assign the :style entry to one of the available options from the sass docs:

:nested
:expanded
:compact
:compressed

The reason it matters, for example, If you're using Sinatra, you set the sass options totally differently:

```
set :sass, :style => :compact # default Sass style is :nested
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help so far! I'm very new to Ruby but I think it is rails that I'm running. I used the http://rubyinstaller.org/ for windows and then ran the gem command to install haml. I now use sass from the ruby command prompt to watch .scss files. 

I am not sure where I am supposed to to the 'setting' of the style? Do you go into the environment.rb file or run a set style command from the command prompt? 

I just ran this: 

set :sass, :style => :compact 

and that didn't change the out put. 

Thanks in advance!